# What do I do with 'amp;' or '&'?

Tags: html

(Not sure exactly how to tag this question, any suggestions please let me know, went with just html tag for now)

I have been given a pixel to place on our website. It's just an img tag with a src attribute like this:

```
 src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?value=1.00&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=abcdefg1234&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/
```

What are '& a m p ;'? Do (added spaces between characters since SO formats as just '&') I need to modify to be like so:

```
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?value=1.00&currency_code=USD&label=abcdefg1234&guid=ON&script=0"/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your instances of `&amp;` to be just `&`, then you can just take out the `amp;` part.

Incidentally, `&amp;` is the HTML character entity that represents the "&" character.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So if I have been provided this img tag from someone, does that mean that it doesn't matter whether I use amp; or &?

Comment: If I were you, I would eliminate the `amp;` part.  It seems like an escaping error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just SO that formats `&amp;` like that, it's all web sites as this is a feature of HTML. They're called "entities" and consist of a sequence of characters beginning with an ampersand and ending with a semicolon. They're a way of describing a character in situations where using the literal character is undesirable. You can find out more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

In the case of your pixel code, they aren't needed (as you discovered) as URLs use a different means of encoding strange characters. It's likely that ill-informed copy and pasting is the culprit for their existence in that URL.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I suspected it was copy paste issue too but was seeking validation here first. Went with @recursive's answer only since he responded first. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can check this in your HTML.

`&nbsp;`    == a space in HTML

`&amp;`    `&`

`&lt;`     `<`

`&gt;`     `>`

`&quot;`   `"`

`&apos;`   `'`

`&` or `&amp;` connect two or more paramters in a request url. Means `and`

Comment: Thanks for the info on this, I wasn't sure when I should use this syntax or not, in this case, since it's URLs I think I can use the regular character '&'

Comment: Technically `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space. It's different from a regular space in that it doesn't count as whitespace when considering text for line-wrapping. An actual space doesn't have a named entity. Named entities aren't supposed to be used in URLs (unless that url is part of text in a chunk of HTML) though servers will usually convert them. You use `&` normally. If you need an ampersand as a non-separating part of your query string, you use `%26`.

Comment: @DougFir Yes,of course. Solving the problem is the gole.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for your supplements.